# Frontend form Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I really like Laravel Nova but it's really complicated for a newbie like me to do something on the frontend that interacts with backend resources.

Can anyone tell me how to make a form insert data into a table from the frontend? Do I need to create a new external model? Can't interact with Nova resources?

Thanks in advance for enlightening me.

My form:

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" placeholder="Introduzca código " name="code">
        @error('code') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ip" placeholder="Introduzca IP " name="ip">
    @error('ip') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="access" placeholder="Introduzca access " name="access">
        @error('access') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    </div><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Crear Asistencia</button>
</form>
```

My function submit:

```
public function submit()
{
    $this->validate([
        'code' => 'required|min:4',
        'ip' => 'required|min:15',
        'access' => 'required|min:1',
    ]);

    Attendance::create([
        'code' => $this->code,
        'ip' => $this->ip,
        'access' => $this->access,
        ]);

    session()->flash('message','asistencia creada correctamente');

    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a crud?

Comment: Yes, I have a form in the frontend with two fields that I want to be included in the database. I'm using livewire but I can't get it to work and I think it's more due to a misunderstanding on my part of how Nova works.

Comment: @TaM have you read the documentation? https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/#introduction, what do you not understand about it?

Comment: I have thoroughly reviewed the documentation but I cannot enter data in my tables from the welcome page in a SPA APP. I think the problem is when accessing the resource created in Nova but there is no information in its documentation if I can do it or how to do it...

Comment: My only doubt is if I have to create a model to work on the frontend or can I work with Nova resources.